# Reduce space between title and chapter

Tags: spacing, chapters

i have been reading how to change that space but I could not. Here is a MWE that reproduces what I have:

I am not sure if it is "Title & chapter", but I upload the image to show what I want to change.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{0pt}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introducción}

\chapter{Estado del arte}

\chapter{Teoría}

\end{document}
```

[image: Here is exactly the space i want to reduce]

Please help!!

Comment: `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\LARGE}`

Comment: Oh, i am ashamed. thank you, now I will try @Moriambar

Comment: Let me know how it goes. Anyway the fifth parameter of the `titleformat` command is the space left between the chapter name and its title. And many many thanks for the MWE

Comment: @Moriambar just another doubt, how can i make numbered those chapters? i mean, change "introduccn" with "1.Introduccn". EDIT: mmh, maybe it is not necessary

Comment: Now, don’t forget that you need `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepacakge[utf8]{inputenc}` to get the accented letters right… :-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti yes, gracias

Comment: I'm adding an answer with all of this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, your problem is in the second of last parameter to `titleformat`.

Your `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\LARGE}` inserts 20 points of space between the word *Chapter* and the chapter name, as stated in the `titlesec` package documentation.

Just rewrite it as:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\LARGE}
```

or tweak the spacing in order to achieve the asked results.

Furthermore I take on Gustavo's suggestion of inserting the `fontenc` and `inputenc` packages in order to accept accented characters, and use type-1 fonts.

Also you should use the `babel` package if you're not using English, with the proper option (I guessed spanish), to correctly parse the language and load the hyphenation codes.

Finally, to meet your requirement of having the number just before the text you should tweak the last parameter.

Here is my example; I think you could start from there

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename}{0pt}{\LARGE\thechapter.\ }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{0pt}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introducción}

\chapter{Estado del arte}

\chapter{Teoría}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Everything worked